Make a half of container with overflow:hidden
As you see on the picture(i attach it below) pacman should've eatten that dot but it went right through him. To prevent this action i made pseudo-element(.pacman::before) and wanted to make it overflow:hidden for hidding dots when it came into pacman's mouth. It doesn't work. Any ideas guys? Or different approach?


/* General Reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Centralized the game */
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: gray;
}

/* Game Container */
.game-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Pacman */
.pacman {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-image: url("../images/pacman1.png");
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: chomping 0.6s linear 1s infinite;
  z-index: 1;
}

.pacman::before {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@keyframes chomping {
  0% {
    background-image: url("../images/pacman1.png");
  }

  16.67% {
    background-image: url("../images/pacman2.png");
  }

  33.33% {
    background-image: url("../images/pacman3.png");
  }

  50% {
    background-image: url("../images/pacman4.png");
  }

  66.67% {
    background-image: url("../images/pacman3.png");
  }

  83.33% {
    background-image: url("../images/pacman2.png");
  }

  100% {
    background-image: url("../images/pacman1.png");
  }
}

/* Dots */
.dots {
  width: 90%;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}

.dots::before {
  content: "";
  width: 400%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, white 30%, transparent 15%);
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  left: 0;
  top: 10%;
  animation: dots-moving 23.5s linear 1s infinite;
}

@keyframes dots-moving {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="game-container">
    <div class="pacman"></div>
    <div class="dots"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>





Here is a different implementation with less of code and easier to adjust


.game-container {
  --s: 60px; /* control the size of the pacman */

  height: var(--s);
  background: radial-gradient(10px, black 98%, #0000) 0/var(--s) padding-box content-box;
  padding-left: calc(var(--s)/2);
  animation: dots .5s linear infinite;
  position: relative;
}
@keyframes dots {
  to {background-position: calc(-1*var(--s))}
}
.game-container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 auto 0 0;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: gold;
  animation: chomping .25s linear infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes chomping {
  0%,15%{clip-path: polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 50%,50% 50%,100% 50% ,100% 100%,0 100%)}
  100%  {clip-path: polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 0  ,50% 50%,100% 100%,100% 100%,0 100%)}
}
<div class="game-container"></div>



